# Cluster records by time using SQL

Tags: sql

I want to cluster records by time and type. I have a table with a timestamp and

a type columns and I want to cluster in the following way:
*If two records are from the same type and their time diff is less than 5 minutes they should be clustered*

*same goes for a record and a cluster, or two clusters*

The result I want for each cluster:
type
start time
end time
number of records

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Comment: which dbms are we talking about?

Comment: When you say "same goes for a record and a cluster, or two clusters", you should really turn the problem around and look for gaps greater than 5 minutes. Your strategy is, order the results by timestamp and compute the difference between each record and the previous record. Then count each series of rows where the gap is less than your desired interval (5 minutes). How you do this will depend on the DBMS.

Comment: I'm using presto
I'll try to simplify the problem - The process I want to run is daily (every day create clusters for the past 24h). Also - It is possible to group the data to time slots of 5 minutes and then do the clustering

Answer (score 0):

Here is SQL example of how it can be done, including data example.
The "events" table has an id, type and time. We want to cluster events by time and type - if the time between two events from the same type is less than 5 minutes. We find gaps between the events from the same type and then count the number of gaps prior to the event - the count result is a cluster id per type:

```
WITH events (id, type, time) AS (
    VALUES
        ROW(1, 1 , now()),
        ROW(2, 1 , now() + interval '10' second),
        ROW(3, 1 , now() + interval '500' second),
        ROW(4, 1 , now() + interval '510' second),
        ROW(5, 2 , now() + interval '500' second)),
gaps AS (
 SELECT id, type, time,
  DATE_DIFF('second', LAG(time, 1 ,time) OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY time), time) > 300 AS gap
  FROM events)
SELECT id, type, COUNT_IF(gap) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY time RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS cluster
FROM gaps
ORDER BY id
```

The result in this example is 3 clusters:
type=1: (id=1,id=2) (id=3,id=4)
type=2: (id=5)